# Not able to Parse JSON Response

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

I am using Python2.7 and simple json module, I am able to get a response but when i want to do something with this JSON Response I am not able to do.

Python Code :

```
        query_url = self.api_url + 'projects'
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(query_url, None, {"Authorization": self._auth})
        handler = self._opener.open(req)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.headers
        raise e
    print simplejson.load(handler)
```

JSON Response:

```
{'start': 0, 'nextPageStart': 166, 'values': [{'description': 'This Repo is created to maintain the code versioning accordingly for My project', 'links': {'self': [{'href': 'https://bitbucket.xyz.xyz/projects/My'}]}, 'id': 757, 'key': 'MY', 'type': 'NORMAL', 'public': False, 'name': 'hub'},{'description': 'Services ', 'links': {'self': [{'href': 'https://bitbucket.xyz.xyz/projects/Hello'}]}, 'id': 1457, 'key': 'HE', 'type': 'NORMAL', 'public': False, 'name': 'Hello'}], 'limit': 25, 'isLastPage': False, 'size': 25}
```

Few data i have removed just kept first and last.

The error which i am observing

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
..."NORMAL", "public": False, "name": "Advi
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Can some body help me here what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: its should be `loads` I think

Comment: i tried with loads it throws following error:    if len(s) > idx:
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__len__'

Comment: what version of python is this?

Comment: Python 2.7.5 and there is limitation to upgrade or downgrade python version.

Comment: can you set 'Content-Type': 'application/json' in headers and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Because your json is invalid. Here it is valid version of your Json data.

First error Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.

Secondly boolean variable in javascprit is lower case. Use `false` instead of `False`

```
{
"start": 0,
"nextPageStart": 166,
"values": [{
        "description": "This Repo is created to maintain the code versioning accordingly for My project",
        "links": {
            "self": [{
                "href": "https://bitbucket.xyz.xyz/projects/My"
            }]
        },
        "id": 757,
        "key": "MY",
        "type": "NORMAL",
        "public": false,
        "name": "hub"
    },
    {
        "description": "Services ",
        "links": {
            "self": [{
                "href": "https://bitbucket.xyz.xyz/projects/Hello"
            }]
        },
        "id": 1457,
        "key": "HE",
        "type": "NORMAL",
        "public": false,
        "name": "Hello"
    }
],
"limit": 25,
"isLastPage": false,
"size": 25
}
```

Comment: This is the response i am getting from my Bitbucket Server.

Comment: If this response is from bitbucket that means their api sends invalid json. You have to correct json otherwise python cannot do this for you. If it is possible can you write a url of this reponse. I will check it.